# Trying to backward through the graph a second time

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to create custom CNN with using Linear layers.
But getting this error:

Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.
File "C:_\DS\RNN\main.py", line 52, in 
loss.backward()
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

Please help, have no idea how to implement similar network to this network:

[image]

The code is:

```python
class MyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n=N):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()
        self.lx = nn.Linear(n, n)
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(n, n)
        self.l1_t = nn.Linear(n, n)
        self.ly = nn.Linear(n, 1)

        self.xt = 0
        self.fn = nn.Tanh()

    def forward(self, x):
        lx = self.fn(self.lx(x))
        l1 = self.fn(self.l1(lx + self.xt))

        self.xt = self.fn(self.l1_t(self.xt + l1))

        x = self.fn(self.ly(l1))
        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

self.xt = tmp.detach().clone()

Did the job.